# Does the Commando perk affect the M4 203?

Tags: killing-floor

I was unsure if the perk grants any of its benefits to the Demolition version of the M4 or not.  I have been struggling to tell, especially since my Commando rank is not very high at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can tell which weapons are affected by certain perks by the icon next to them in the shop.
If you see the commando icon next to the M4 203, then it is affected by commando, if not, then it isn't.
Most perks also state all of the weapons affected by it in its description, so you should be able to find the answer there as well.

EDIT: I just checked up on the [Killing Floor Wiki](http://kf-wiki.com/wiki/M4_carbine) and it seems that only the M4 is affected by commando perk, and the M4 203 is only affected by the demolitions perk.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the M4 203 gains both the bullet damage and clip size benefits from the Commando perk.

The latter can easily be seen — at Commando rank 3 and above, the M4 203's clip size will be 37 rather than the default 30.

Answer (score 1):

You are both wrong. I have tested this myself.

The commando holding the m4 203 gets clip size bonuses and recoil bonuses. That is all.

It does not get a discount nor damage bonuses to the bullets fired and grenades launched.